# Find the density function of $2T_1+T_2$

Tags: probability, actuarial-science

A device containing two key components fails when, and only when, both components fail. The lifetimes, $T_1$ and $T_2$, of these components are independent with common density function $f(t) = e^{-t}$, $t > 0$ . The cost, $X$, of operating the device until failure is $2T_1 + T_2$.

---

And here's the solution:
The joint density of $T_1$ and $T_2$ is given by 
$$
f(t_1,t_2)=e^{-t_1}e^{-t_2},t_1>0,t_2>0
$$
Therefore,
$Pr(X\leq x)=Pr(2T_1+T_2\leq x) ......step$ $one$
$=\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}(x-t_2)}e^{-t_1}e^{-t_2}dt_1dt_2......step$ $two$
......

---

What I didn't understand is how you can go from step one to step two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We look the easier case first, $P(a_1 \leq Y_1 \leq a_2,b_1\leq Y_2 \leq b_2) = \int_{b_1}^{b_2} \int_{a_1}^{a_2}f(y_1,y_2)dy_1dy_2$. You need to compute the integral over the rectangle region $[a_1,a_2]\times[b_1,b_2]$.

Back to your question, $P(2T_1+T_2 < x)$, and $t_1,t_2>0$, so what you need to do is to find the integral region on $(t_1,t_2)$-plane. The region of $t_1$ goes from the line $t_1=0$ to $t_1=\frac{1}{2}(t_2-x)$, and when $t_1$ is given, the region of $t_2$ is from $0$ to $x$.